# Creating widget with button in .kv file

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I have a widget with one button.
*SimpleWidget.py*

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class SimpleWidget(Widget):
    bt = ObjectProperty()
```

*.kv*

```
<SimpleWidget>:
    bt: button

    Button:
        id: button
```

How do I create this widget inside .kv with different handlers for buttons?
I tried to do this with this code

```
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        SimpleWidget:
            bt.on_press: print('1')
        SimpleWidget:
             bt.on_press: print('2')
```

Or

```
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        SimpleWidget:
            self.button.on_press: print('1')
        SimpleWidget:
             self.button.on_press: print('2')
```

In both cases, an exception is thrown

```
 ...
      23:    BoxLayout:
      24:        SimpleWidget:
 >>   25:            bt.on_press: print('1')
      26:        SimpleWidget:
      27:            bt.on_press: print('2')
 ...
 Invalid property name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a property on the widget.

**SimpleWidget.kv**

```
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        SimpleWidget:
            number: 1
        SimpleWidget:
            number: 2

<SimpleWidget>:
    number: 0
    Button:
        id: button
        on_press: print(root.number)
```

**SimpleWidgetApp.py**

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MainScreen(Widget):
    pass

class SimpleWidget(Widget):
    pass

class SimpleWidgetApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SimpleWidgetApp().run()
```

Comment: Is there a solution for arbitrary handlers? I need to write the code inside kv similarly `on_press`.